# AngularJS directive not behaving as expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this directive I'm trying to get to work. Here is what SHOULD happen. On the initial page load it runs a navCheck() function. If the location.path() === '/index' it adds some classs for changing on scrolling. If the location.path() is anything other than '/index' it should just set the classes for the nav and not enable the scrolling. I accomplish this after the inital load by using $locationChangeSuccess. Everything executes the expected way, but even when the location.path() is not 'index' it still adds the scroll bind. What am I missing??

```
.directive('changeClass', ['$window', '$location', '$rootScope',
    function ($window, $location, $rootScope) {
        var offset = "50";

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                var navCheck = function() {
                    if ($location.path() === "/index") {
                        console.log('this path is index');
                        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function () {
                            if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(offset)) {
                                element.removeClass("navbar-transparent");
                                element.addClass("navbar-primary")
                            } else {
                                element.addClass("navbar-transparent");
                                element.removeClass("navbar-primary")
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log('anything other than index');
                        element.removeClass("navbar-transparent");
                        element.addClass("navbar-primary")
                    }
                };
                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
                    navCheck();
                    console.log('location changed')
                });
                navCheck();
            }
        };
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.directive('changeClass', ['$window', '$location', '$rootScope',
    function ($window, $location, $rootScope) {
        var offset = "50";

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                var indexOnScroll= function () {
                            if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(offset)) {
                                element.removeClass("navbar-transparent");
                                element.addClass("navbar-primary")
                            } else {
                                element.addClass("navbar-transparent");
                                element.removeClass("navbar-primary")
                            }
                        };
                var navCheck = function() {
                    if ($location.path() === "/index") {
                        console.log('this path is index');
                        angular.element($window).on("scroll",indexOnScroll);
                    } else {
                        console.log('anything other than index');
                        angular.element($window).off("scroll",indexOnScroll);
                        element.removeClass("navbar-transparent");
                        element.addClass("navbar-primary")
                    }
                };
                $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function() {
                    navCheck();
                    console.log('location changed')
                });
                navCheck();
            }
        };
    }])
```

You forgot to `unbind` from the scroll on `else` condition. I prefer `on` and `off` than `bind`  and `unbind` since  jQuery officially deprecated all binding syntaxes other than `.on` .